# How get values categories an count products for each category in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `Category`:

```
id    name
1     test1
2     test2
3     test3
4     test4
5     test5
```

Table `Products`:

```
CategoryId      name
1              product1
1              product2
1              product3
1              product4
3              product5
3              product6
3              product7
5              product8
5              product9
```

*For get names category we use:*

```
SELECT Name FROM Category
```

*But how get count products from table `Products` for each category from table `Category` in this query with command `left join` ?*

Comment: @GordonLinoff in result i would like get next rows `test1 4, test2 0, test3 3, test4 0, test5 2`. I've done it before, but now forgotten how to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
SELECT category.name, COUNT(category_id) 
FROM category LEFT JOIN product ON category.id = product.category_id
GROUP BY id
```

and the output will be

```
test1   4
test2   0
test3   3
test4   0
test4   2
```